# vim: how to show buffer numbers in the 'args' command output

Tags: vim, numbers, buffer, args

When one types `args` command in vim, one is shown a list of currently edited files (buffers). However, if the list of files is long (for example, more than 20), it is very hard to tell what buffer number a given file name corresponds to without manually counting them. The goal is to be able to check quickly buffer number a given file corresponds to and jump to it using the `b`(+bufferNumber) command.

Is there a way to append or prepend the shown (using `args` command) file names with their buffer numbers?

Some examples of expected output:

```
1 fileName1
2 fileName2
```

or

```
fileName1 1
fileName2 2
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you want to navigate buffers so you should use a command that lists buffers, not a command that lists arguments.

> one is shown a list of currently edited files (buffers).

No. One is shown a list of arguments, that may or may not have corresponding buffers.

> it is very hard to tell what buffer number a given file name corresponds to without manually counting them.

The position of an argument in the argument list is not guaranteed to match with its corresponding buffer's position in the buffer list, if it even has one.

> The goal is to be able to check quickly buffer number a given file corresponds to and jump to it using the `b`(+bufferNumber) command.

There already is a command for that: `:help :buffers`.

Basically, there is no guaranteed relationship between a "file", an "argument", and a "buffer" so one should use commands adapted to the object one is trying to manipulate. Listing arguments in order to navigate buffers is utterly pointless.

You are confusing and conflating a bunch of notions, here: "files", "arguments", and "buffers". To be honest, Vim's own command names and documentation can be confusing so here is a high-level explanation.

- "Files" are the files on your disk. You may think in "files" terms when you do something at that level of granularity ("I want to edit the `README.md` of this project." or "I want to write the content of this buffer to file `foo.rb`") but, outside of that use case, there are more appropriate mental models.

  If you think in "files", use commands that deal with filesystem I/O, like `:help :w`, `:help :r`, etc.
- Conceptually, "arguments" are the filenames provided to Vim at startup:

  ```
  $ vim foo.rb bar.spec.rb
  ```

  But, of course, it became possible to change the argument list at runtime so it sort of lost its original meaning and it is probably more useful to think of "arguments" as "filenames": you have a list of filenames whose initial value is the filenames passed as argument to Vim upon startup, to which you can add entries and from which you can remove entries.

  If you want to manipulate arguments, use argument-oriented commands like `:help :argdo`, `:help :next`, etc.

  NOTE: the documentation uses the word "file" a lot in the context of the argument list where it should use the more appropriate "argument".
- "Buffers" are exactly what you would call "document" in other more familiar programs. They *can* be associated to a "file" or an "argument" or not.

  If you want to manipulate buffers, use buffer-oriented commands like `:help :buffers`, `:help :bufdo`, etc.

  NOTE: if you check the documentation for `:buffers` you will see that it has two synonyms, `:files` and `:ls`, which makes things pretty confusing. The list you get *may* map to actual "files" on your disk *or not* so the distinction between "files", "arguments", and "buffers" is important.

Comment: `:buffers` (and its synonyms `:files` and `:ls`) directly solve my problem, but the rest of the discussion is very educational as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@romainl answered this question very well, however since I had something nearly like laying around

```vim
command! -nargs=* -bang -bar -complete=file Args
      \ if empty(<q-args>) |
      \   if <bang>0 |
      \     execute "argdelete *" |
      \     Args |
      \   else |
      \     for i in range(argc()) |
      \       if argidx() == i |
      \         echohl Directory | echo printf("%3d %s", bufnr(argv(i)), argv(i)) | echohl None |
      \       else |
      \         echo printf("%3d %s", bufnr(argv(i)), argv(i)) |
      \       endif |
      \     endfor |
      \     echohl Title |
      \     echo '(' . min([argidx() + 1, argc()]) . ' of ' . argc() . ') ' . argv(argidx()) |
      \     echohl None |
      \   endif |
      \ else |
      \   args<bang> <args> |
      \ endif
```

This creates a new command `:Args` which has the following attributes:

- `:Args!` - clears argument list
- `:Args` - shows arguments with each file on separate line with bufnr
- `:Args` - highlights current argument
- Can be used the same as `:args ...`

Comment: The custom `Args` command works as expected and also directly solves my problem. Actually, `Args` produces a nicer and more easy to read output than the build in `:buffers` (and its synonyms `:files` and `:ls`)! Thank you!